# Unexpected token when initializing state in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

When i try to initialize state in a component it gives me 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token at

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFromDatePicked = false,
      isToDatePicked = false,
      markedDates = {},
    }
  }
```

`isFromDatePicked = false` line. I also tried to initialize the state outside of the constructor but is not worked at all too.

Also, when i remove state initialization in order to test the code it gives me same error at

```
 let markedDates = { ...this.state.markedDates };
      let [_markedDates, range] = this.setupMarkedDates(this.state.fromDate, this.state.toDate, markedDates);
      if (range >= 0) {
        this.setState({ isFromDatePicked: true, isToDatePicked: true, markedDates = _markedDates });
```

`markedDates = _markedDates` line.

I have no idea why it is throwing such error. And any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:` instead of `=` inside `{}`. From the [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Creating_objects)

> However, the advantage of the literal or initializer notation is, that you are able to quickly create objects with properties inside the curly braces. You simply notate a list of `key: value` pairs delimited by comma

Also use `this` before `state`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFromDatePicked:false,
      isToDatePicked:false,
      markedDates:{},
    }
  }
```

And also in `setState` you are passing a object so use `:` instead of `=`

```
this.setState({ isFromDatePicked: true, isToDatePicked: true, markedDates :_markedDates });
```

Comment: I'm so blind that I couldn't see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlkanV Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: you can define state in constructor like that .        this.state={}